# Assembly language to C code?

Tags: recursion, assembly

I'm trying to figure out what this block of assembly code is doing:

```
mystery:
.LFB0
    testl   %edi, %edi
    je      .L3
    subq    $8, %rsp
    shrl    $2, %edi
    call mystery
    addq    $1, %rax
    jmp     .L2
.L3:
    movl    $l, %eax
    ret
.L2:
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

So far I have this as the C code:

```
long mystery(unsigned n){
    if(n==0)
       return 1;
```

And I get that there is a recursive function going on here while n!=0 but I don't understand what the %rsp register is doing

Comment: `rsp` is the stack pointer. The compiled code is allocating 8 stack bytes, doing the recursive call `return 1 + mystery(n / 4)`,  removing the 8 bytes to restore the stack before the return is completed.  The add/remove is probably to comply with the ABI for stack frame alignment. It ultimately has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

int64_t mystery(int32_t n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 1 + mystery(n / 4);
}
```

I don't know what the `$l` is in the line:

```
movl    $l, %eax
```

so my above solution assumes it's a typo for `$1`.  Enlighten me.